# How to select element by attr in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I will convert an application I developed with Jquery to Vue JS.

I used the function below to select an element.

**Jquery Code:**

```
function setColor(row,col) {
var element=$('[data-row=' + row + '][data-row=' + col + ']');
 element.addClass("bg-red");
}
```

How can I do the same with Vue JS?

Comment: Please share how you have tried it in vue so far.

Comment: I have not tried a solution with Vue js. @Tuna

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$refs`

Add your element to `ref="yourRef"`, you can select it using by `this.$refs.yourRef[0].$el` in method

For Class styling you can use `v-bind:class`

Comment: I know this method, but it wasn't the solution I wanted.
That's why I created the method of adding all the elements to an array and searching within the array.

Answer (score -2):

Using `document.querySelector` you can try like this

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[data-row="'+ row + '"][data-cell="' + cell +'"]');
element.addClass('bg-red')
```

or use the class and style bindings

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html